# trialkyl phosphine ligands in aqueous micellar Suzuki-Miyaura coupling

Tags: catalysis

I have seen $\ce{P(tBu)3HBF4}$ salt used as a precursor to the phosphine ligands for aqueous Pd-catalyzed micellar Suzuki-Miyaura coupling, but why does it work - after $\ce{Et3N}$ has liberated the tributyl phosphine ligand why does it not deactivate in the presence of water?

Comment: And how you imagine "deactivation"?

Comment: Well there is a likelihood of free radical chain oxidation if there is oxygen present, which is why I thought it was odd that it was apparently stable for a reaction performed in water

Comment: It's not like it spontaneously combusts - it's not a problem if some of phosphine gets oxidised, isn't it added in surplus either way?

Comment: The phosphine ligand probably coordinates to palladium rather quickly, and the complex is air-stable (in the solid state at least). That may not render the reaction immune to oxygen, but likely does increase its resilience to it.

Comment: ok excellent cheers